# How to position ngshow messages in angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

How to have ng-show messages beside the text box rather than underneath it. Right now it is displaying all the validation messages underneath the input box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script>
            "use strict";
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.cityArray = ["hyderabad", "secunderabad", "delhi", "mumbai"];
                $scope.submit = function ($event) {
                    if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
                        // Or some other update
                        $scope.myForm.$submitted = true;
                        $event.preventDefault();
                    }
                };
            });
            app.directive('uniqueUsername', function ($http) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    require: 'ngModel',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                        element.bind('blur', function (e) {
                            ngModel.$setValidity('unique', true);

                            $http.post('CheckUserName2.do').success(function (data) {
                                if (data) {
                                    ngModel.$setValidity('unique', false);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-0">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <h2 class="text-muted">Registration form</h2>
                                <div>
                                    <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" >
                                        First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" unique-username="" placeholder="First Name" required/>
                                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
                                        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span><br/>
                                        <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
                                        <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofYFZNyxozZt5It8ArWc?p=preview)

Comment: Where beside it? You don't have space to the right.

Comment: Exactly. How to create space next to it. I am not very good with css

Comment: Then you can't have input full width.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have space to the right to display error messages beside the input box. Putting error messages just above the submit button will cause a minor UI issue: with each error, your form submit-button will flicker vertically. 
Viz. 
- Submit your form without entering any input to get the error message.
- type/erase any character in the input box to see the flickering

**Workaround:**

Either keep the error messages below submit button or provide dedicated height to error messages to avoid undesirable effects or both

```
  <form name="myForm" action="RegistrationServlet.do" method="POST" >
      First name:<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="uname" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]{3,20}/" ng-model="uname" unique-username="" placeholder="First Name" required/><br><br>
      <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="submit($event)">Submit</button>
      <div style="height=100px">
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.pattern">First name cannot be less than 3 letters with no digits</span>
        <span style="color:red" class="error" ng-if="myForm.$submitted && myForm.uname.$error.required">Please fill field above<br></span><br/>
        <span style="color:red" class="hide-while-in-focus" ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.unique">Username already exist<br/></span>
      </div> 
  </form>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/yDaUIrELRgcUC6bUnQPB?p=preview)

Comment: Sounds good. However, I have about 10 fields and user might have to scroll down to see the error messages. Alternatively, Is it possible to adjust the input fields next to each other to make the form look small ( I mean to reduce the overall height so that I can avoid scrolling)

Comment: May be a error message like this showing on the right: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://designm.ag/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/01-ideal-forms-3-preview-screenshot.jpg&imgrefurl=http://designm.ag/ui-design/tips-resources-enhanced-checkout-forms/&h=450&w=850&tbnid=NaF5ikwpzdzM3M:&zoom=1&docid=cyQNdL7KAi_DtM&ei=CjmNVdiBNcmOuATroqmYCA&tbm=isch&ved=0CBsQMygXMBc4ZA

Comment: @kittu: Something like this ? http://plnkr.co/edit/yDaUIrELRgcUC6bUnQPB?p=preview

Comment: Exactly, That's what I am looking for but slightly with little more space on the right to display text unfolded

Comment: Use `col-xs-12` instead of `col-md-6` for your `<div>`. text-wrapping is due to small window size. See [this](http://embed.plnkr.co/yDaUIrELRgcUC6bUnQPB/preview)

Comment: Unable to change button width with `col-xs-12`